# PyCharm 2016: How to display result without print command (like console)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a Python command:

```
(2.5).as_integer_ratio()
```

I want to see result:

```
(5, 2)
```

like in the command line console, but I don't want use print command inside PyCharm.

```
a = (2.5).as_integer_ratio()
print(a)

// Result:
// (5, 2)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Select all** or select code block, then right click, choose **Execute selection in Console**

Specific on Mac OS (El Captain):

Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,
then <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, you will see result at the bottom of PyCharm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Python Console" (at the bottom of the screen):

```
>>> (2.5).as_integer_ratio()
(5, 2)
```